# How to connect 2 Apple Thunderbolt Displays to Windows PC with Asus ThunderboltEX 3 Expansion Card, if Possible?

Tags: windows-10, macos, multiple-monitors, thunderbolt

I was able to connect one thunderbolt display to my windows PC because I'm using an Asus thunderboltEX 3 PCI-E card. However, I bought another thunderbolt display, connected it to my first one in order to use it through daisy chaining, and the second one doesn't work display an image, but I am able to access the speakers in it play audio through it.

Is there something I have to do to get the second one to fully work in terms of software, or do I need another adapter? The thunderbolt software for the asus thunderboltEX card detects both displays.